# Swift error "Expected expression in container literal" with variable declaration

Tags: swift

The message "Expected expression in container literal" continues to appear in the variable line. Code attached below:

```
import ResearchKit

public var ConsentDocument: ORKConsentDocument {

let consentDocument = ORKConsentDocument()
consentDocument.title = "Example Consent"

let _: [ORKConsentSectionType] = [
var consentSection: [ORKConsentSection] = consentSectionTypes.map { contentSectionType in
let consentSection = ORKConsentSection(type: contentSectionType)
consentSection.summary = "x."
consentSection.content = "y."
return consentSection
}
```

So sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Show some context. Show the full function this is in. Show us relevant variable declarations.

Comment: I tried it in a playground and didn't get any errors.  (I made dummy structs to represent the types used in the one line of code you bothered to give us.)

Comment: That code snippet does not make sense. You start to declare an array using `= [` but instead of putting a value, you start declaring variables inside the array declarations like if you were in a function.